# useEffect doesn't reload child component when its state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a react component structure like this:

[image]

In my table component, I have an option to trigger a modal that prompts user to give some input, which will then send a put request to the backend. In code it looks something like this:

```js
const ParentContainer = (): JSX.Element => {
 const dataToPassDown = useSelector((state:IRootState) => selectData(state));
 return (
    <ParentComponent data={dataToPassDown}/>
  )
}


const ParentComponent = (props): JSX.Element => {
 const {data} = props;
 return (
   <MyHeader data = {data}/>
   <MyTable data = {data.tableData} />
 )  
}


const MyTable = (props): JSX.Element => {
 const {data} = props;
 const [inputFromModal, setInputFromModal] = useState("");
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(putRequest(inputFromModal);
 }, [inputFromModal]);

 return (
   <Modal visible={false} updateInputValue={setInputFromModal}/>
   <Table ... />
 )  
}
```

I want to refresh (only) the table component once the modal closes, but in this current setup, `useEffect` doesn't reload the table component when its state (`inputFromModal`) changes. Was I wrong in thinking that `useEffect` would reload the component when the state changed?

Comment: If `<Modal visible={false` then how is Modal opening/closing? I think you have missed some details.

Comment: can you show the code that open and close the modal? right now its statically written visible=false

Answer (score 0):

It is not part of `useEffect` to re-render your component.
component will re-render when its state is changing or Parent component re-render.

By using `useEffect`, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. (or in this case after every change of `inputFromModal`.
it means that you are making put request every time `inputFromModal` is being changed.

For conclusion, in order to re-render your component, you need the data props to be updated by parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one point here, your table will be **re-render** only when the **parent components re-render** or the **state of your MyTable Component changes**, now the data which you are taking from props, set it in your state so that whenever that data changes your component will re-render

```
const MyTable = (props): JSX.Element => {
 const {data} = props;
 const [inputFromModal, setInputFromModal] = useState("");
 const [tableData, setTableData] = useState();
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(() => {
   setTableData(data)
 }, [data]);
 
 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(putRequest(inputFromModal);
 }, [inputFromModal]);

 return (
   <Modal visible={false} updateInputValue={setInputFromModal}/>
   <Table ... />
 )  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vikas, am i correct in saying that since `inputFromModal` is a state of MyTable, changing it will cause My Table to re-render, however, since the data shown in this table, i.e. in props from Parent didn't change, the re-render will effectively show the same component from before?

Comment: yes, actually when you are changing inputFromModal the data from props is still the same , so your table doesn't re-render  but with the same data